# Issue Playing Apple Music Song with playbackStoreID

Tags: ios, swift, mpmusicplayercontroller, apple-music, apple-musickit

I am trying to play an individual apple Music song using a playbackStore Id but whenever I attempt to play it I get this error 
[image: error presented by xcode]

The user is properly authenticated and the playback store id seems to be valid. I was wondering if anyone else is having this issue or knows what could be causing it. Here is the code that is causing the error.

```swift
applicationMusicPlayer.setQueue(with: [songSelected.playbackStoreID])
applicationMusicPlayer.repeatMode = MPMusicRepeatMode.none
applicationMusicPlayer.play()
```

And the application Music Player is an MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having a similar problem and I was able to fix it by switching from applicationMusicPlayer to systemMusicPlayer. You won't be able to play music locally in your app ( :( ), but at least you'll be able to play music